# Typescript - Function with bound generic type 'not assignable' to extended type

Tags: typescript, generics, types

I have a base type `Base` and I want to create an object that holds functions which receive some subtype of `Base` (`ExtendsBaseA` or `ExtendsBaseB` in this case) and map it to another type `C`.

I've tried to declare *"some subtype of `Base`"* as `<T extends Base>`, but the type check fails with the following:

> Type '(baseA: ExtendsBaseA) => C' is not assignable to type '(base: T) => C'.
>
> Types of parameters 'base' and 'baseA' are incompatible.
>
> Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'ExtendsBaseA'.
>
> Type 'Base' is not assignable to type 'ExtendsBaseA'.
>
> Property 'b' is missing in type 'Base'.

**Snippet**

```
interface Base {
    a: string
}

interface ExtendsBaseA extends Base {
    b: string
}

interface ExtendsBaseB extends Base {
    c: string
}

interface C {}


class Foo {
    private readonly handlers: {
        [key: string]: <T extends Base> (base: T) => C
    }

    constructor() {
        this.handlers = {
            'bar' : this.handler
        }
    }

    handler(baseA: ExtendsBaseA): C {
        return <C>null;
    }
}
```

[Try it here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=interface%20Base%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20a%3A%20string%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20ExtendsBaseA%20extends%20Base%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20b%3A%20string%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20ExtendsBaseB%20extends%20Base%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20c%3A%20string%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20C%20%7B%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Foo%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20private%20readonly%20handlers%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5Bkey%3A%20string%5D%3A%20%3CT%20extends%20Base%3E%20(base%3A%20T)%20%3D%3E%20C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.handlers%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20'bar'%20%3A%20this.handler%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20handler(baseA%3A%20ExtendsBaseA)%3A%20C%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20%3CC%3Enull%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D)

Any ideas on how to solve this?

**Edit:** Strangely enough if I change:

```
[key: string]: <T extends Base> (base: T) => C
```

to:

```
[key: string]: (base: Base) => C
```

It works on the playground but not when I try it on my local Typescript installation. (both are 2.9.1)

Comment: Turn on `strictFunctionTypes` in the Playground to see the error.

Comment: How would you plan to use `handlers`?  If each property is a function that only handles *some* subtype of `Base` instead of *all* subtypes of `Base`, then there's no way to call it with any parameter (since you never know if the `Base`  object you have is the "right" one for the function).  Either make your functions accept *all* subtypes of `Base`, or make a typesafe way of dispatching each `Base` to the proper handler function.  If you can detail how you plan to actually use `handlers` I might be able to make a concrete suggestion.

Comment: @jcalz Thanks for the playground tip. So I have different subtypes of `Base` that I want to handle differently, and a `type` string property on `Base` that helps me uniquely distinguish them. I want to dispatch the appropriate `handler` function using the `Base.type` string: `this.handlers[obj.type](obj)`.

Comment: @jcalz I guess these are called *"discriminated unions"* and typescript can handle them using type guards. However in this case I just want to stop the type system from getting in the way and just let me do it by indexing the map. I guess I could do `[key: string]: (base: any) => C` but `any` feels way too permissive as my function arguments are always subtypes of `Base`. It just felt that there would be a way to do this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you plan for `handlers` to be a map whose key corresponds to the discriminant of a discriminated union, you should be able to represent that type exactly.  Let me flesh out the types you have to include the discriminant:

```
interface Base {
  type: string
  a: string
}

interface ExtendsBaseA extends Base {
  type: "ExtendsBaseA"
  b: string
}

interface ExtendsBaseB extends Base {
  type: "ExtendsBaseB"
  c: string
}

interface C { }

type BaseUnion = ExtendsBaseA | ExtendsBaseB;
```

Note that you need to explicitly declare the union, as in `BaseUnion` above.  Now we can define the type `HandlerMap` as follows.

```
type HandlerMap = { 
  [K in BaseUnion['type']]?: (base: Extract<BaseUnion, { type: K }>) => C 
}
```

If you inspect this, it looks like:

```
type HandlerMap = {
  ExtendsBaseA?: (base: ExtendsBaseA) => C,
  ExtendsBaseB?: (base: ExtendsBaseB) => C
}
```

Now you can define your `Foo` class like this:

```
class Foo {
  private readonly handlers: HandlerMap;

  constructor() {
    this.handlers = {
      ExtendsBaseA: this.handler // changed the key
    }
  }

  handler(baseA: ExtendsBaseA): C {
    return <C>null!;
  }

}
```

And that all works, as far as it goes.  Still, you'll find it frustrating to write a type safe function which takes a `HandlerMap` and a `BaseUnion` and tries to produce a `C`:

```
function handle<B extends BaseUnion>(h: HandlerMap, b: B): C | undefined {
  const handler = h[b.type] 
  if (!handler) return;
  return handler(b); // error, no valid call signature
}
```

The TypeScript compiler's control flow analysis isn't sophisticated enough to understand that the argument to `h[b.type]` will always correspond exactly to the type of `b`.  Instead, it sees that `h[b.type]` accepts *some* constituent of `BaseUnion`, and that `b` is *some* constituent of `BaseUnion`, and balks at the possibility that they don't match up.  You can assert that they do match up, which is probably the best you can do:

```
function handle<B extends BaseUnion>(h: HandlerMap, b: B): C | undefined {
  const handler = h[b.type] as ((b: B) => C) | undefined; 
  if (!handler) return;
  return handler(b); // okay
}
```

Hope that's of some help.  Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, took me a while to understand what `Extract` does but got there in the end :)

Answer (score 2):

I wasn't happy with the suggested requirement for having a union class that knows about all of the extending class/interfaces, so I looked a little further into a way to work around the issue.

It's worth noting that the error is relatively legitimate - the system can't know that what we're doing is always valid, so it tells us so.   So we basically have to work around the type safety - as jcalz does with the `as ((b: B) => C)`

I approached it from the other direction - tell the compiler that *internally* I know what I'm doing with the type safety on registration, instead of on callback, but I do still want to correctly type the handlers to derive from the base class.

So here we go:

Registration/Dispatcher:

```
interface Base {
    type: string;
}

export type Handler<T extends Base> = (action: T) => void;
type InternalHandler = (action: Base) => void;

export class Dispatcher {
    private handlers: { [key: string]: InternalHandler } = {};

    On<T extends Base>(type: string, extHandler: Handler<T>) {
        const handler = extHandler as InternalHandler;
        this.handlers[type] = handler;
    }

    Dispatch(e: Base) {
        const handler = this.handlers[e.type];
        if(handler) handler(e);
    }
}
```

the events:

```
export class ExtendsBaseFn implements Base {
    type: 'Fn' = 'Fn';
    constructor(public cb: () => void) { };
}

export class ExtendsBaseNN implements Base {
    type: 'NN' = 'NN';
    constructor(
        public value1: number,
        public value2: number,
    ) { }
}
```

the handler:

```
export class ObjWithHandlers {
    constructor() {
        global.dispatcher.On('Fn', (baseFn: ExtendsBaseFn) => {
            baseFn.cb();
        });
        global.dispatcher.On('NN', (baseNN: ExtendsBaseNN) => {
            console.log(baseNN.value1 * baseNN.value2);
        });
    }
}
```

the driver:

```
(global as any).dispatcher = new Dispatcher();
const placeholder = new ObjWithHandlers();
```

and finally, users:

```
global.dispatcher.Dispatch(new ExtendsBaseFn(() => console.log('woo')));
global.dispatcher.Dispatch(new ExtendsBaseNN(5, 5));
```

notes:

- added to global / placeholder for minimal example purposes
- I like the event definitions as classes for the nice constructor, ease of use, clarity, and safety.  As opposed to an interface + a create function, making everyone write the `{ type: 'xxx' }` themselves, or the individual variable names.  So convenient!
- C in this minimal example is void.  the return type of the function is ancillary to the actual typing question here.

I'm revisiting this answer occasionally to improve as I learn and expand the system and safeify:

- Static member types (v3 - super simplified)
- typeguard check on child classes (without having parent/child dependencies)

```
export interface IDerivedClass<T extends Base> {
    type: string;
    new (...args: any[]): T;
}

export class Base {
    // no support for static abstract - don't forget to add this in the derived class!
    // static type: string;

    type: string = (this.constructor as IDerivedClass<this>).type;

    Is<T extends IDerivedClass>(ctor: IDerivedClass<T>): this is T {
        return (this.type === ctor.type);
    }
}

export class ExtendsBaseNN extends Base
{
    static type = 'NN';
    ...
}

// show dispatcher ease of use
dispatcher.On(ExtendsBaseNN.type, (nn: ExtendsBaseNN) => {...})

// show typeguard:
const obj: Base = new ExtendsBaseNN(5,5);
if (obj.Is(ExtendsBaseNN)) return obj.value1 * obj.value2;
```

Comment: Nice approach. Also, did you mean `Handler` instead of `ActionHandler`?

Comment: thanks, and confirmed+edited.  (my local code is Action everything)